# Different between NSData and NSMutableData in iPhone

Tags: nsdata, nsmutabledata

What is the difference between NSData and NSMutableData?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Stack Overflow tag-wikis:

[nsdata](/questions/tagged/nsdata)

> The NSData class is an apple class for holding generic data. Often
>   used when reading/writing from and to files, and the internet.

[nsmutabledata](/questions/tagged/nsmutabledata)

> NSMutableData (and its superclass NSData) provide data objects,
>   object-oriented wrappers for byte buffers.

Answer (score 3):

`NSData` is fixed after creation.

`NSMutableData`, as the name implies, allows operations that change the contents (`appendBytes:`, `appendData`, `setData:`...).